# Ensure implementation of component input and output angular 4

Tags: angular

I would like to create an interface that enforces whoever implement in to use `@Input()` and `@Output()`.

This is my interface :

```
export interface BannerInterface {
  currentEvents: Input,
  _bannerClick: Output
}
```

And my component which implements it:

```
  @Input()
  set currentEvents(currentEvents: any[]) {
    this.currentEvent = currentEvents[0];
  }

  @Output() _bannerClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

This gives me an errors that I'm incorrectly use the interface.
I understand that interface can enforce types and not decorators (the interface I've build can't use those types), but I was wondering if there's a way that I can enforce properties to be `@Input()` and `@Output()`.

Comment: so basically you can enforce decorators? I don't think that's even remotely possible and needed

Comment: This is what I want to achieve.. enforce every component witch implement this interface to have certain properties witch are Input() and Output()

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: @Maximus I have a parent component witch holds many small components  . Every time one component is loaded with dynamic component loader (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). I want all of the components to have the same input and output bindings because this is how I communicate with them.

Comment: `@Input` and `@Output` have no effect on dynamic components. Read [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d) to understand why

Answer (score 0):

You could use an abstract class for each component:

```
export abstract class Component {
    @Input()
    abstract set currentEvents(currentEvents: any[]);

    @Output()
    abstract get output();
}

export class FooComponent extends Component{
    set currentEvents(currentEvents: any[]) {
        //Your implementation.
    }

    get output() {
        //Your implementation.
    }
}
```

I don't have tools to test this at the moment but this should work because decorators follow inheritance. Anyways, I don't see a use case where you'd want to do this.